# Price calculation logic changes in opencart

Tags: e-commerce, opencart

I am new to opencart. I am trying to make a jewellery shop where price of gold and diamond will be saved in config file and i have to calculate the final price of the product according to weight of the material used in the product. Could you please provide a reference material or inputs for the same.

Comment: Have you tried writing any code?

Answer (score 0):

Check out these extensions that do exactly what you want from opencart:
http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&filter_search=sell%20by%20weight

Comment: thanks a lot for input ...but could you please tell where to make changes in files ...i don't want any extension.

Comment: @user3192931 if you don't want to use extensions, you may copy the content inside it manually (like if you were the vqmod processor)